# IP Address cannot obtain in ESP-IDF?

Tags: ip-address, esp32, esp-idf, espressif-idf, serial-monitor

I am making application using **ESP32** in **ESP-IDF**. I am new to ESP-IDF. I am trying to get temperature and humidity data from ***AHT25*** and update that into server.
This is main.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/event_groups.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_wifi.h"
#include "esp_event.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "nvs_flash.h"
#include "esp_netif.h"
#include "esp_http_server.h"
#include "esp_netif.h"

#include "aht25_library.h"

static EventGroupHandle_t s_wifi_event_group;

static httpd_handle_t server = NULL;

#define EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID      "Saranya's Galaxy 
 F22"     
#define EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS      "saran142407"
#define EXAMPLE_ESP_MAXIMUM_RETRY   5

#define I2C_PORT           I2C_NUM_0
#define I2C_SCL_PIN        22
#define I2C_SDA_PIN        21

#define WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT BIT0
#define WIFI_FAIL_BIT      BIT1

static const char *TAG = "wifi station";

static int s_retry_num = 0; 

static void event_handler(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id, void* event_data)
{
if (event_base == WIFI_EVENT && event_id == WIFI_EVENT_STA_START) {
    esp_wifi_connect();
} else if (event_base == WIFI_EVENT && event_id == WIFI_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED) {
    if (s_retry_num < EXAMPLE_ESP_MAXIMUM_RETRY) {
        esp_wifi_connect();
        s_retry_num++;
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "retry to connect to the AP");
    } else {
        xEventGroupSetBits(s_wifi_event_group, WIFI_FAIL_BIT);
    }
    ESP_LOGI(TAG,"connect to the AP fail");
} else if (event_base == IP_EVENT && event_id == IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP) {
    ip_event_got_ip_t* event = (ip_event_got_ip_t*) event_data;
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "got ip:" IPSTR, IP2STR(&event->ip_info.ip));
    s_retry_num = 0;
    xEventGroupSetBits(s_wifi_event_group, WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT);
}
}
void wifi_init_sta(void)
{
s_wifi_event_group = xEventGroupCreate();

ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());
esp_netif_create_default_wifi_sta();

wifi_init_config_t cfg = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_init(&cfg));

esp_event_handler_instance_t instance_any_id;
esp_event_handler_instance_t instance_got_ip;
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(WIFI_EVENT,
                                                    ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID,
                                                    &event_handler,
                                                    NULL,
                                                    &instance_any_id));
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(IP_EVENT,
                                                    IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP,
                                                    &event_handler,
                                                    NULL,
                                                    &instance_got_ip));

wifi_config_t wifi_config = {
    .sta = {
        .ssid = EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID,
        .password = EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS,
        .threshold.authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_PSK,
    },
};
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_STA));
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_config(WIFI_IF_STA, &wifi_config));
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_start());

ESP_LOGI(TAG, "wifi_init_sta finished.");

EventBits_t bits = xEventGroupWaitBits(s_wifi_event_group,
        WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT | WIFI_FAIL_BIT,
        pdFALSE,
        pdFALSE,
        portMAX_DELAY);

if (bits & WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT) {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "connected to ap SSID:%s password:%s",
             EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID, EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS);
} else if (bits & WIFI_FAIL_BIT) {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Failed to connect to SSID:%s, password:%s",
             EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID, EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS);
} else {
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "UNEXPECTED EVENT");
}
}


static esp_err_t root_handler(httpd_req_t *req)
{
float temperature, humidity;
esp_err_t err;

err = aht25_read_temperature(I2C_PORT, &temperature);
if (err != ESP_OK) {
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Error reading temperature");
    httpd_resp_send_500(req);
    return ESP_FAIL;
}

err = aht25_read_humidity(I2C_PORT, &humidity);
if (err != ESP_OK) {
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Error reading humidity");
    httpd_resp_send_500(req);
    return ESP_FAIL;
}

char json_response[128];
snprintf(json_response, sizeof(json_response),
         "{\"temperature\": %.2f, \"humidity\": %.2f}", temperature, humidity);

httpd_resp_set_type(req, "application/json");
httpd_resp_send(req, json_response, HTTPD_RESP_USE_STRLEN);
return ESP_OK;
}

void http_server_task(void *pvParameters)
{
httpd_config_t config = HTTPD_DEFAULT_CONFIG();
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Starting HTTP server on port: '%d'", config.server_port);
if (httpd_start(&server, &config) == ESP_OK) {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "HTTP server started successfully");

    httpd_uri_t root_uri = {
        .uri       = "/",
        .method    = HTTP_GET,
        .handler   = root_handler,
        .user_ctx  = NULL
    };
    httpd_register_uri_handler(server, &root_uri);
}

vTaskDelete(NULL);
}


void app_main()
{
esp_err_t ret = nvs_flash_init();
if (ret == ESP_ERR_NVS_NO_FREE_PAGES || ret == ESP_ERR_NVS_NEW_VERSION_FOUND) {
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_erase());
    ret = nvs_flash_init();
}
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(ret);

ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());

esp_netif_create_default_wifi_sta();

wifi_init_config_t wifi_config = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_init(&wifi_config));

i2c_config_t i2c_config = {
    .mode = I2C_MODE_MASTER,
    .sda_io_num = I2C_SDA_PIN,
    .scl_io_num = I2C_SCL_PIN,
    .sda_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
    .scl_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
    .master.clk_speed = 100000
};
i2c_param_config(I2C_PORT, &i2c_config);
i2c_driver_install(I2C_PORT, I2C_MODE_MASTER, 0, 0, 0);

aht25_init(I2C_PORT);

xTaskCreate(http_server_task, "http_server_task", 4096, NULL, 5, NULL);

esp_netif_ip_info_t ip_info;
    if (esp_netif_get_ip_info(esp_netif_get_handle_from_ifkey("WIFI_STA_DEF"), &ip_info) == ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "IP Address: " IPSTR, IP2STR(&ip_info.ip));
    } else {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to get IP address");
    }
    }
```

aht25_library.c

```
#include "aht25_library.h"
#include "driver/i2c.h"

#define AHT25_I2C_ADDRESS   0x38


#define AHT25_READ_TEMP_COMMAND 0x01
#define AHT25_READ_HUMI_COMMAND 0x02
#define AHT25_INIT_COMMAND  0xE1

esp_err_t aht25_init(i2c_port_t i2c_port) {
  i2c_cmd_handle_t cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();


i2c_master_start(cmd);
i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, (AHT25_I2C_ADDRESS << 1) | I2C_MASTER_WRITE, true);

i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, AHT25_INIT_COMMAND, true);

i2c_master_stop(cmd);

esp_err_t ret = i2c_master_cmd_begin(i2c_port, cmd, pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
i2c_cmd_link_delete(cmd);

return ret;
}


esp_err_t aht25_read_temperature(i2c_port_t i2c_port, 
float *temperature) {

i2c_cmd_handle_t cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();
i2c_master_start(cmd);
i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, (AHT25_I2C_ADDRESS << 1) | I2C_MASTER_WRITE, true);
i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, AHT25_READ_TEMP_COMMAND, true);
i2c_master_stop(cmd);
esp_err_t ret = i2c_master_cmd_begin(i2c_port, cmd, pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
i2c_cmd_link_delete(cmd);

if (ret != ESP_OK) {
    return ret; // Return the I2C communication error
}

uint8_t temp_data[3];
ret = i2c_master_read(i2c_port, temp_data, sizeof(temp_data), I2C_MASTER_LAST_NACK);
if (ret != ESP_OK) {
    return ret; // Return the I2C communication error
}

return ESP_OK;
}

esp_err_t aht25_read_humidity(i2c_port_t i2c_port, float *humidity) {

i2c_cmd_handle_t cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();
i2c_master_start(cmd);
i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, (AHT25_I2C_ADDRESS << 1) | I2C_MASTER_WRITE, true);
i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, AHT25_READ_HUMI_COMMAND, true);
i2c_master_stop(cmd);
esp_err_t ret = i2c_master_cmd_begin(i2c_port, cmd, pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
i2c_cmd_link_delete(cmd);

if (ret != ESP_OK) {
    return ret; // Return the I2C communication error
}

uint8_t humi_data[3];
ret = i2c_master_read(i2c_port, humi_data, sizeof(humi_data), I2C_MASTER_LAST_NACK);
if (ret != ESP_OK) {
    return ret; // Return the I2C communication error
}
return ESP_OK;
}
```

aht25_library.h

```
#ifndef AHT25_LIBRARY_H
#define AHT25_LIBRARY_H

#include "driver/i2c.h"
#include "esp_err.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
#endif

#define AHT25_I2C_ADDRESS   0x38 

esp_err_t aht25_init(i2c_port_t i2c_port);

esp_err_t aht25_read_temperature(i2c_port_t i2c_port, float *temperature);

esp_err_t aht25_read_humidity(i2c_port_t i2c_port, float *humidity);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* AHT25_LIBRARY_H */
```

There is no error in my code, but ip address cannot be displayed on serial monitor. it is displayed like 0.0.0.0

[image]

Can anyone help me? I am new to this tool.